# Using ios google sign in api - what are those two values?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking at the sample `AppDelegate.swift` file from Google stored on their git hub: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/c2830d8413097c79117a0f9519e9af14aaeb4587/ios/signin/SignInExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift

and there is this method:

```
  @available(iOS 9.0, *)
  func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
      sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String?,
      annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
  }
```

can you tell me what exactly is the `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey` and `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the key for extracting source annotation & source application.
UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey - source annotation

UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey- source application

Earlier we get this values ready made from the method parameters.Now in iOS 9 we need to fetch it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, can I use `func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {` instead?

Comment: You have to use both version of open URL functions in order to support of iOS 9+ and also iOS 9 below